# I need to replace the content of the variable in jinja2 template using ansible replace module when it satisfies when condition

Tags: variables, ansible, jinja2

I need to replace the content of the variable in jinja2 template using ansible replace module.

and in the same jinja2 template I need to replace some values when It satisfies the when condition. The when condition should be in jinja2 templates only.

I have tried in couple of way as shown below but none of them were worked for me

do we have any way to use the when condition in the same jinja2 template.

```
- set_fact: result="{{ temp |  replace('nodeAgent', ''+value+'') | replace('nodeServrer', ''+result+'') when: (''+adu+'' == 'adt') }}"
- set_fact: result="{{ temp |  replace('nodeAgent', ''+value+'') | replace('nodeServrer', ''+result+'') |  when: (''+adu+'' == 'adt') }}"
```

Comment: Please get familiar with [if](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#if) statement.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
{% if '+adu+' == 'adt' %}
nodeAgent
{% else %}
nodeServer
{% endif %}
```

Comment: here the if condition only applicable for node server. How would I do this.

Comment: With an if only and removing the else